# Spring boot rest endpoint result inconsistent because of in memory caching?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have Spring boot app deployed on 4 instances of ECS on AWS FARGATE. (I'm new to it.)

In my app, we have pure java in memory cache.

Assuming I put data using /putdata and get data using /getdata

When i hit /getdata, it sometimes returns results and sometime it doesn't.

1. is there a possibility that my /putdata went to one of the 4 instances and only that In memory cache has that data, other 3 instance don't have it?
2. OR my spring boot object states are managed to stay in sync on all 4 instances?

in summary, does rest requests land on different ECS container and may behave different if it lands on other ECS instance next time?

Comment: What do you mean by `pure java in memory cache`? If you're talking about variables within the program, then they won't be shared between instances. In that case, yes, the results of requests could be different if the requests land on different instances. You can try using a separate in-memory database like Redis when trying to share data between instances.

Comment: Are you saying your Spring Controller (/getdata) is inconsistent. It returns different return values?  Most of the Spring Apps i use are deployed to EC2 and I have never seen this functionality.

Comment: @smac2020 i think GabrielPizarro got my problem in above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve this, you need a centralize cache server and point all your ECS instance/spring boot application to that cache server.

either you could go with **AWS's managed cache server(ElsticCache)** which is totally managed by AWS OR you need to spin some EC2 instance and install some distributed cache server in it. These are few you can give a try **Hazelcast, Redis, Apache Ignite,etc**

i would suggest go with AWS ElasticCache(Redis),so you don't have to manage anything. best of luck.

Comment: Agreed to solution. is there any raw approach in java like if one instance receives request, it communicates to other instances?